# rmarkdown returning not found on shiny server

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny-server

I have successfully installed R Shiny server on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-1025-azure x86_64). I want to host interactive documents and I have installed rmarkdown `sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('rmarkdown', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""` but rmarkdown box returns not found on myserver:3838. The ramrkdown file is not also available under 
`@ShinyUbuntu:/srv/shiny-server$ ls
index.html  sample-apps`

[image: rmarkdown not found on myserver:3838]

Comment: There should be two directories in `/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps`: `hello` with the shiny app and `rmd` with the Rmarkdown document. Do you see both directories? Was the installation of `rmarkdown` successful? In which library is it installed? Did you try restarting the shiny-server after installation of rmarkdown?

Comment: Only the sample-apps directory is available. rmarkdown_1.18 was successfully installed in `‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’`. I tried restarting without success

Comment: What is the content of the `sample-apps` directory?

Comment: it has a `hello` and `rmd`

Comment: And what is the content of the `rmd` durectory? What do you get when you open <your-server>/sample-apps/rmd/? Anything in the log-files (`/var/log/shiny-server` and `/var/log/shiny-server/rmd-*`)?

Comment: In the `rmd` directory there is `index.rmd`. When I run `<myserver>:3838/sample-apps/rmd/index.Rmd` the shiny doc loads. But with `<myserver>:3838/sample-apps/rmd/` it returns `Not Found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204049/discussion-between-ralf-stubner-and-keniajin).